# escaping square brackets from string in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe where i am try to clean the data from all cols. There are some annomalies in teh data like this:
`"[n], [ta], [cb]"`
basically anything in square brackets i want to ignore and replace with a space.
I have this:

```
df['data1'] = df['data1'].str.replace(r"\[(n|ta|cb)\]", " ")
```

this works except I still get the square brackets in the data but they are just empty.
Not sure how to also remove the square brackets as well as the letters in it. Also not sure if there is a quicker way to do this on all columns and not just one at a time.

Comment: That should remove the square brackets, too. It should just leave the commas and spaces.

Comment: It works for me...

Comment: weird it wont remove the brackets for me even though i escaped them.

Comment: Please post code that initiazes a test dataframe so that we all work on the same thing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Demonstrating `pd.DataFrame({"data1":["[n], [ta], [cb]"]})['data1'].str.replace(r"\[(n|ta|cb)\]", " ")[0]` gives us `' ,  ,  '`. OP won't give us the data that produces the problem, so time to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I think the reason why you previously got remaining square brackets was because you didn't include the escape character `\` (back slash).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':['[n], [ta], [cb]']})
```

Without escape characters:

```
df['data1'].str.replace(r"[(n|ta|cb)]", " ")

# 0    [ ], [  ], [  ]
# Name: data1, dtype: object
```

With escape characters:

```
df['data1'].str.replace(r"\[(n|ta|cb)\]", " ")

# 0     ,  ,  
# Name: data1, dtype: object
```

To apply this to all columns, just use a for loop:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r"\[(n|ta|cb)\]", " ")
```

Comment: But OP clearly shows the escape characters in the question. It could be that the cells contain python lists. If you want to do the replace on all columns, you could `df = df.replace(r"\[(n|ta|cb)\]", " ", regex=True)`.